# Specify what type of singularity there is.

Tags: complex-analysis

What type of singularity do we have at $0$ in $f(z)=\frac{1}{(2cos(z)-2z^{2}-2)^2}$

Is it enought to find at which step (and if) the derviative of denuminator won't be equal $0$ at $0$?

Comment: What can you say on $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ ?

Comment: Needed to change the function due to an honest mistake while typing.

Comment: It doesn't change anything to my comment. What can you say on $1/f(z)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. From 
$$
f(z)=\frac14 \cdot\frac{1}{(\cos(z)-z^{2}-1)^2}
$$one may use the Taylor series expansion of $\cos(\cdot)$, as $z \to 0$, giving
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac14 \cdot\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^4}{24}-\frac{z^6}{120}+O(z^8)-z^{2}-1\right)^2}
\\\\&=\frac1{4}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{9 z^4}{4}-\frac{z^6}{8}+O(z^8)}
\\\\&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{9 z^4}+\frac{1}{162 z^2}+O(1)}
\end{align}
$$ then the given function admits a pole of order $4$ at $z=0$.

Comment: I am so sorry, I got the function wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(z)=2 \cos z-2z^2-2$. Then it is easy to see that $g$ has a zero of order $2$ at $0$. Hence $g^2$ has a zero of order $4$ at $0$. This gives:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{(2cos(z)-2z^{2}-2)^2}$ has a pole of order$4$ at $0$